# How do you setup MONIT to monitor php5-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx, monit

One of the solutions I found is this:

```
check process php5-fpm with pidfile /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
   group php 
   start program = "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start"
   stop program  = "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop"
   if failed unixsocket /tmp/php-fpm.sock then restart
   if 4 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
   depends on nginx
```

This does not work because the following file does not exist in my system:
`/tmp/php-fpm.sock`

When I run `sudo find / -name *.sock` I get:

```
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock
/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock
/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock
```

If it helps, this is the file I change to configure how php behaves with the particular domain I use : `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/web2.conf`.  So MAYBE the right file is `/var/lib/php5-fpm/web2.sock ?

This is a VPS with ubuntu 12.04 and nginx 1.4.4.